# Get img tag from HTML element

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML content. I want to get "foo.jpg" and store in a variable.

```
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum congue justo et facilisis. Fusce sed vulputate magna. Praesent lacinia justo ligula, a mattis enim rhoncus vitae. Quisque nec porttitor lectus. Aenean tempor magna eu egestas tincidunt. Morbi vitae mi at mauris hendrerit blandit. Nunc iaculis vitae velit at dignissim. Vestibulum vitae gravida mi. </p>
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo"></img>
</div>
```

I found this

```
var myimg= document.getElementById("imgid").src;
```

but it not will not since i dont know the image id, and because it not document but element 
I trying to find something like this `mycontnet.html.img[0].src`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByTagName()`:

```js
var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
console.log(myImg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum congue justo et facilisis. Fusce sed vulputate magna. Praesent lacinia justo ligula, a mattis enim rhoncus vitae. Quisque nec porttitor lectus. Aenean tempor magna eu egestas tincidunt. Morbi vitae mi at mauris hendrerit blandit. Nunc iaculis vitae velit at dignissim. Vestibulum vitae gravida mi. </p>
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo" />
</div>
```

Comment: can i change document to the element name like. myitem..getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src?

Comment: @yanivz No, if you want to access any element in an HTML page, you always start with accessing the document object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the img element because the id is not present on the 
 img tag. Either you can use `getElementByTagName()` method or you can add `id` attribute on the img tag. If you will use `src` it will give you the full URL of the image if you just need the image name, you can use the `getAttribute()` method.

```js
const src = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
```

```js
const src = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
console.log(src);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
  <img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use any css selector to find your image using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), for example.:

```js
document.querySelector('img').src
```

or be more specific and modify your selector to match unique result (you could have multiple img tags at your page, so it's best to specify at least it's parent)

- `div > img`
- `.image-wrapper img`
- `img.image`

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever id to your image tag like this

`<img src="foo.jpg" id="myImg"/>`
or
`<img src="foo.jpg" id="logo"/>`

then you have to use this id "myImg" or "logo" to call the image tag

`var myimg= document.getElementById("myImg").src;`
or
`var myimg= document.getElementById("logo").src;`

**Try pasting this in your html file and look in the console**

```
<img src="foo.jpg" id="myImg"/>
<script>
var myimg= document.getElementById("myImg").src;
console.log("MY IMAGE SOURCE IS "+myimg)
</script>
```